# insert using dblink in procedure not working

Tags: oracle

The procedure is now inserting data after I inserted an exception but the new issue is it is inserting the same row in emp1 table twice.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc1 IS
      CURSOR b IS SELECT environment FROM emp;
      v VARCHAR2(11);
 BEGIN
      OPEN c;
      LOOP
          FETCH b INTO v;
          CASE v
               WHEN 'a' THEN INSERT INTO emp1@testlink SELECT empno, name FROM emp
               WHEN 'b' THEN INSERT INTO emp1@testlink1 SELECT empno, name FROM emp
          END CASE;
      END LOOP;
 EXCEPTION
      WHEN case_not_found THEN dbms_output.put_line('No data');
 CLOSE b;
```

Comment: If you execute this proc shows an error? Have you tried to run the insert command outside the procedure? Have you checked if the table **emp1** has permissions to insert?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes it shows an error ORA-06592: CASE not found while executing CASE statement

Comment: Edited the post and now it inserts the same row twice. Any help is appreciated

Comment: @user1815823: if this proc inserts the same row twice maybe the query: **SELECT environment FROM emp** returns the same row.

Comment: Yes the ask is that the environment will be the same even for 5 or 6 rows but the column datas will be different. so, if the environment is same for 5 rows it has to process one by one

Comment: @user1815823: Sorry but i do not understand,  if you can post an example with data.

Comment: Sorry I didn't elaborate and thanks for helping me through this. The rows are given below and even if the environment is the same it has to insert 3 rows of dev1 and two rows of dev2 but it is inserting 6 rows(each row is inserted twice) dev1 and 4 rows of dev2(each row is inserted twice) in the remote DB                Environment        Empno     Name
Dev1                10001      Mike
Dev2                10002      Randy
Dev1                10003      Harris
Dev1                10004     John
Dev2                10005     David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you researched the error message, you would have determined that the error has nothing to do with your dblinks. Here is the relevant information:

```
ORA-06592: 
CASE not found while executing CASE statement 
Cause: A CASE statement must either list all possible cases or have an else clause.
Action: Add all missing cases or an else clause
```

So, you have a value for "environment" that is neither 'a' nor 'b'.  If having other values is valid, then you need to add cases for them, or add an ELSE clause to catch those values with some default action.

```
case v
         when 'a' then insert into emp1@testlink select empno, name from emp
         when 'b' then insert into emp1@testlink1 select empno, name from emp
         else <<do something here>>
    end loop;
```

Comment: thanks, I did that before and edited the post. now it is inserting the same row twice

Comment: Well, then you have multiple rows in EMP with the same values for ENVIRONMENT.  Have you printed out the values of your cursor to see what the results are, or just run the cursor select as a query?

Comment: Since I am testing I have only row for environment but is still inserts twice in the target table

Comment: You are missing an exit condition for your loop: EXIT WHEN b%NOTFOUND;  BTW, you can do away with all the cursor open/fetch/close business by using a cursor for loop - http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/cursor_for.php